# Handling Json Deserialization with multiple lines

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

My application expects Json files coming in two different structure. One file where each line is a complete json and other file which is a Json file.
For ex : one file will have this structure

`{"Logging": {"LogLevel": {"Default": "Warning", "System": "Warning", "Microsoft": "Warning" }}}`

and other file with this structure:

```
{"Logging": {"LogLevel": {"Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }}}
```

my below code does the deserialization and it works for first structure but fails for other file saying error as

> *Unexpected end when reading token. Path ''."}*

My code :

```
foreach( var line in lines )
            {
   var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( line);}
```

I would like to know how can I fix this so that it handles files of both types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading each line of your JSON file into the data variable trying to parse each line.

So it tries to parse line 1, which is *{"Logging": {"LogLevel": {"Default": "Warning",*. and since that is not a valid JSON object the parsing fails.

Instead use `File.ReadAllText` to read the entire file into a single string, then parse the string. Or simply Join the string array back into a single string:

```
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,lines));}
```

Comment: But wont this effect my first file since there I have multiple lines in a file and each line is a complete Json

Comment: Do them separately. You could name the one JSON structure per file files as `.JSON`. And the other kind as something like `.Json-grp`. Then have your code treat them differently

Comment: thats actually i can do, one i already have as .jsonl as json lines. Thanks